# Lender benefits/perks comparison website or resource?

Tags: united-states, loans, comparison, benefits

I was trying to research different lender housing loans in the US.  I realize only the true rates and approved amounts would be after meeting with each lender and going through their pre-approval process, but some lenders have features or perks along with their loans.  Something like BillShrink, but for loans and the best deals out there.  Chase for example has a small % discount on your payments for people that hold a chase checking account and chase home loan.  They do this for their auto loans also.  Maybe other companies have similar or different kinds of benefits?

I know there are many credit unions out there and other options, but curious if their were some central resources on loan perks/benefits of at least some of the more well known lenders.

Answer (score 1):

[Bankrate.com](http://Bankrate.com) is great for researching CDs, checking and saving accounts and also has info for mortgages and insurance.  They list both local and online results.

Lendingtree.com works for you to do the search and find you the best loans (mortgage, home equity, auto loan) and also for insurance and credit cards.